# Spring 3 - Accessing messages.properties in jsp

Tags: validation, spring-mvc

I am new using spring 3 and have been stuck for a while on this.

Do you know how can I access messages.properties from a jsp. For instance, in the controller I set a value to my model:

```
model.setError("user.not.found")
```

messages.properties:

```
user.not.found=Sorry, we haven't been able to found this user
```

and in the jsp I want to be able to do

```
${model.error}
```

and displaying "sorry...". However I always get "user.not.found" even if this works fine when I use the @Valid ..., bindingResult and then  in the form.

Thanks,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `<spring:message>` from the `spring` taglib:

```
<spring:message code = "${model.error}" />
```

where taglib is imported as

```
<%@ taglib prefix = "spring" uri = "http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
```

Comment: And here's the taglib reference: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/spring.tld.html

Comment: Is possible to get message from messageSource without using tags, i mean some expression like ${msg['code']} ?

Comment: @marioosh: I guess, there are no easy ways.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `${msg.getMessage('MSG_CODE')}` in JSP, if you put message resolver into the Model(or ModelAndView) in the controller.

```
// In a controller class

...

@Autowired
private MessageResolver messageResolver;

...

@RequestMapping(value="/edit")
public ModelAndView getSomething(MyFormData formData,
                                 ModelAndView mv) {
    mv.setViewName("TARGET_VIEW");

    // Do some controller things...

    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("msg", messageResolver);

    mv.addAllObjects(map);

    return mv;
}
```

And in JSP, you can use `${msg.getMessage('MESSAGE_CODE')}`.
The big advantage of this approach is that you can use Message even inside the Spring Form Tags. `<spring:message code="MESSAGE_CODE" />` can not be used inside the Spring Form Tags.

```
<form:select path="domainObj1.property1" cssClass="form-control">
    <form:option value="" label="--${msg.getMessage('L01006')}--" />
    <form:options items="${selection.selectionList}" itemValue="code" itemLabel="codeVal"/>
</form:select>
```

It is even better that you implement a custom Interceptor(specifically, the postHandle method) to put the messageResolver into the ModelAndView rather than you write the same code in all controllers.