# spring:message with EL code

Tags: java, spring, el

I want to get text from spring:message with var text send by controller like this.

```
<spring:message code="${user.city.country.i18n_key}"/>
```

${user.city.country.i18n_key} can be "spain", "england", "france", etc...

But not found... Any way to do?

SOLUTION:
Clean project and rebuild... I don't know...

Comment: What is `user`,`city`,`country`,`i18n_key` ? Where are they defined ?

Comment: This looks like property replacement. What are you trying to do?

Comment: ${user.city.country.i18n_key} can be "spain", "england", "france", etc... Is a variable send to jsp from controller.

Comment: I send one i18n_key in var, for example "spain", in country_xx.properties i have the key "spain" translate in differents languages "Spain" (en) "España" (es), etc...

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4864487/1907906

Comment: where did you define property?