# Use spring tag in XSLT

Tags: java, html, xslt, spring-mvc, tags

I have a **XSL/XML** parser to produce **jsp/html** code.

Using **MVC** model I need to accees spring library in order to perform **i18n** translation.
Thus, given the xml

```
<a>
  ...
  <country>EN</country>
  ...
</a>
```

and using `<spring:message code="table_country_code.EN"/>` tag, choose based on the browser language, the transalation into England, Inglaterra, etc... 
However, the XSL do not support `<spring:message>` tag.
The idea is to have a XSLT with something like this

```
<spring:message code="table_country_code.><xsl:value-of select="country"/>"/>`
```

to have the final code `<spring:message code="table_country_code.EN"/>` and be recognized in the final JSP/HTML based on i18n translation.

I also tried to create the spring tag in **Java** when I make a parse to create the **XML** but I sill have the same error.

```
The prefix "spring" for element "spring:message" is not bound.
```

[EDIT]

I saw some questions here, like using `bean:spring` but still have the same problem.
any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSLT has to be namespace well formed XML, so you need to declare the namespace and you can not use `<` in attribute values.

[Spring 3 - Accessing messages.properties in jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864469/spring-3-accessing-messages-properties-in-jsp)

suggests the namespace should  be

```
http://www.springframework.org/tags
```

so presumably you want an XSLT code of

```
<spring:message 
  xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags"
  code="table_country_code.{country}"
/>
```

where `{}` is an *attribute value template* that evaluates the XPath `country`

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, when the HTML is loaded through XSLT the spring do not convert the code, i.e. but keeps the `<spring:message 
  xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags"
  code="table_country_code.EN"/>` message instead of England. 

Any ideia why?

Comment: I have one JSP with one div where is loaded another JSP page witch calls the XSLT transform.. the inside JSP have this code

`<c:set var="xmltext">
    ${form.xmlResponse}
   </c:set>
   <c:import url="template.xsl" var="xslt"/>
   <x:transform xml="${xmltext}" xslt="${xslt}"/>`

Comment: You haven't really given enough information but JSP is a server-side technology and if you are running the XSLT on the client in the readers browser it is too late, if you are generating JSP you need to generate the markup _on the server_

Comment: @X-Pippes run xslt on the server (or in advance of putting the files on the server) to generate the document you serve rather than serving a call to xslt but that may or may not fit into your architecture, impossible to tell.

Comment: the XSLT is on the server side, because the JSP and XSLT call is loaded in server, right? Javascript runs on browser (client side) but JSP is loaded on server, I guess.
Is there any way to force a "refresh" on spring?

Comment: @X-Pippes no idea never used spring but it is anyway a different question

Comment: OK I will create a new one. Thanks anyway. +50 for your help